# Opening a webpage from an AutoCompleteBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, html, autocompletebox

I'm using Windows Phone 8, I've got an AutoCompleteBox up and running, it pulls its suggestions from a Class file, I just need to be able to link the search term that the user types into the AutoCompleteBox to carry across and open in Google and the page that is displayed is the google search results page for that search term. Any Ideas on how to do this? Would it be to do with the SelectionChanged event handler?

Comment: are you using MVVM pattern?

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan thanks for your reply, I'm not sure what that is and I'm pretty sure I'm not using it, would you elaborate for me please?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Have you found anything out?